# Cannot create/edit Cortana channel for Azure web-app bots

Tags: azure, botframework, cortana

I created a web bot in Azure portal and trying to configure a Cortana channel, but getting this message as soon as I open the Cortana channel page:

```
Sorry, something went wrong.
Trace Id : cd98143f-91cc-4a21-8d0e-b19c3bb2c5fc
```

I was able to do it couple weeks ago, but now I cannot edit the Cortana channel I previously created, the same error appears.

The same problem is reproducible with another bots on different accounts.

Comment: Is your bot setup via a subscription on a company or organizational tenant or a personal subscription?

Comment: @StevenKanberg, it's a personal subscription.

Answer (score 1):

If the issue persists, please try this possible fix: https://github.com/microsoft/cortana-skills-samples/tree/master/Consumer/CSharp/V4Patches

Hope of help!

Comment: The Cortana channel error message magically disappeared even before I tried the v4 patch. I am able to edit the channel right now.
Anyway, thanks for your help!